# PHP error_reporting - different results on 2 servers

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP site and using my Mac as the development machine. I then upload the site to a Windows server for external testing. The site has a .php file that sets the appropriate error_reporting values.

I've just noticed that on my Mac Server I'll get this warning in the log file:

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

but on the Windows server the same error appears in the browser, despite using the same error_reporting settings.

I'm newish to PHP so still have a lot to learn but don't understand how the same site can have different error reporting results on different servers?

Comment: `display_errors`, probably. error_reporting determines what PHP reports as errors. display_errors determines whether they're shown at all, and where.

Comment: it could be due to different version of PHP

Comment: Show all error related php.ini settings and we will tell you.  But @MarcB probably nailed it.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB - it was the difference in display_errors. Was OFF for my Mac but On for Windows server. Learn something new every day . . .

Comment: @user982124 To make your code more portable you can use a local config file that sets things like that. This will override the settings in php.ini, so you don't have to worry about differences in server configuration.

Comment: If Marc B doesn't submit an answer based on his comment, submit your own answer and mark it accepted so the question is not listed unanswered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was the difference in the display_errors setting as Marc B pointed out